# Is it possible to 'style' icons in Android?

Tags: android

For example, I downloaded an icon from Google which is simply a check mark. I put this icon in my app's action bar but unfortunately the icon is black and my action bar is quite dark so it doesn't look good. Is there a way to style the icon automatically or do I have to edit the png to be white instead? I found [this website](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) which mentions styling an icon but I'm not sure if that's a guideline for a designer or actually something that goes into code.

What is the standard way to style icons? Do I need to download black and white icons and use the appropriate one at runtime based on the app theme? That seems like it could be a pain.

Comment: Google provides every icon in black and white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For myself, if I need to style an icon, I use photoshop to edit the icon. But any image processing software should work if you are familiar with it.
However, the icons you mentioned that are available online usually come with both a dark and light theme. So if you have a dark action bar theme, you can simply download and use the light version of the icon.

For your checkmark icon specifically, you can download either the light or dark version of it [here](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_check_box), [here](https://design.google.com/icons/index.html#ic_check), or [here](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_check_circle). Hope this helps.

Comment: That's where I got my checkmark from, I just didn't notice I could choose to download a white version.

Answer (score 0):

look at this web site http://bitdroid.de/Android-Material-Icon-Generator/

for any question or how it work: http://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/programming/tool-android-material-icon-generator-t3333159

Comment: Thanks for sharing this great resource!

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the answer in the answer instead of just linking to off-site resources as they may disappear over time.